# python timer thread shutdown

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I am trying to create a timer working thread, which can exit at any time.
python has a build in timer, whose callback function is called only ONCE?!
I have no idea why it is called timer.

Then I have to put a sleep in the working thread, which is a bad idea. timerThread.cancel() cannot shutdown the working thread. If I use event to exit the working thread, the working thread can exit only after wake up.

I am expecting a timer working thread, which can exit at any time. and I don't want the working thread blocked.

Are there some ways to realize it?

```
def Show():
    while 1:
        time.sleep(10)
        print("Nice!")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    timerThread = threading.Timer(1,Show)
    timerThread.start()
    while 1:
        input = str(sys.stdin.readline())
        if input == 'EXIT\n':
            timerThread.cancel()
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your point, the Timer object [1] in python runs just once and after some period of time executes a function. That function, though, can start a new Timer object. An example of this implementation is below.

```
timerThread = None

def timesUp():
    global timerThread
    print('Nice!')
    timerThread = Timer(10, timesUp)
    timerThread.start()

def main():
    global timerThread
    timerThread = Timer(10, timesUp)
    timerThread.start()
    while 1:
        input = str(sys.stdin.readline())
        if input == 'EXIT\n':
            timerThread.cancel()
            break;
```

Overall, due to GIL [2] issues in python, you'll have issues with threading properly, as only 1 thread has access to the interpreter at a time. This is why a lot of frameworks in python are single threaded, asynchronous frameworks (e.g. gevent [3], tornado [4]). Instead of using threads they listen on an IOLoop (eventlets, epoll) and cooperatively yield operation flow to the other waiting coroutines.

[1] - https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects

[2] - https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

[3] - http://www.gevent.org/

[4] - http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/

Comment: timerThread.cancel() does not work. the working thread is still working

Comment: I really don't understand, If the Timer executes only once, why it is named timer???!!!

Comment: I don't know about the origins of the word but a timer could be thought of as something like an egg timer. After this many seconds ding a bell. It doesn't reset itself, it takes you to reset it. Similar to that, this timer needs you to set it each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class to solve your problem.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

class Timer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, seconds, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        assert callable(callback)
        self.__callback = callback
        self.__seconds = seconds
        self.__args = args
        self.__kwargs = kwargs

        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            Thread(target=self.__callback, args=self.__args, kwargs=self.__kwargs).start()
            time.sleep(self.__seconds)

    def stop(self):  
        self.running = False
```

To call this function use

```
def Test(spam,eggs=10):
     print spam, eggs

timerFunction = Timer(1,Test,10,eggs=99) # The number 1 is the time in seconds
timerFunction.start()
```

To stops the execution use:

```
timerFunction.stop()
```